# Matlab vectorization of for loops

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Is there any way to vectorize such a for loop in MATLAB? It's taking a lot of time to execute.

```
for i = 1:numberOfFrames-1
    frameDifferencesEroded(:,:,i+1) = imabsdiff(frameDifferencesErodedTemp(:,:,i+1),frameDifferencesErodedTemp(:,:,1));
    for k=1:numel(frameDifferences(1,:,i))
        for m=1:numel(frameDifferences(:,1,i))
            if(frameDifferencesEroded(m,k,i+1)>thresold)
                frameDifferences(m,k,i+1) = 255;
            else
                frameDifferences(m,k,i+1) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hint: focus on vectorizing the inner loops (over `k` and `m`) - those are straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `frameDifferencesEroded(:,:,1)` and `frameDifferences(:,:,1)` to be all zeros, as you are not inputting values into those with your code, this might work for you -

```
%// Replace imabsdiff with abs(bsxfun(@minus..)), which might be faster
frameDifferencesEroded = abs(bsxfun(@minus,frameDifferencesErodedTemp, frameDifferencesErodedTemp(:,:,1)))

%// Get the thresholding done next
frameDifferences = (frameDifferencesEroded>thresold).*255
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try somehting like this:

```
[M, N, P] = size(frameDifferences);
for i = 2:P
    frameDifferencesEroded(:,:,i) = imabsdiff(frameDifferencesErodedTemp(:,:,i),frameDifferencesErodedTemp(:,:,1));

    frameDifferences(:, :, i) = (frameDifferencesEroded(:, :, i) > thresold) .* 255;
end
```

Do you need to keep `frameDifferencesEroded`? If not you can make it a temporary 2-D matrix inside this loop.
But try to rearrange your data by swapping the 1st and 3rd dimension: `m(i,:,:)` are stored in memory consecutively, whereas `m(:,:,1)` are not which might make it slower.